# Calling a method from ABL code not working

Tags: progress-4gl, erp, epicorerp

When I create a new quote from Epicor I would like to add an item from the parts form automatically.

I am trying to do this using the following ABL code which runs when 'GetNewQuoteHed' is called:

```
run Update.
run GetNewQuoteDtl.
run ChangePartNumMaster("Rod Tube").
ttQuoteDtl.OrderQty = 5.
run Update.
```

I am getting the error:

> Index -1 is either negative or above rows count.

This error occurs for each line in my ABL code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the proper format for a 4GL error message (nor is it at all familiar) so I'd say it is an Epicor application message.  Epicor support is probably your best bet.  However... Just guessing but it sounds like you might need to somehow initialize the thing that you're updating.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Tom, but i would also say try and isolate the error and see where the error is raised as soon as you find the point the error is actually raised it is normally much easier to figure out exactly what is going wrong and how to solve it.

Working between a 0 based and a 1 based system there can be issues with the 1st or last entry depending on which way you moving. As the index for 0 based systems starts at 0 and ends at n-1 where 1 based systems start at 1 and end at n.